# How to get and set time input value?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an input with type "time".

```
<input type="time" id="time1" value="18:00">
```

Now, if I try to get the default value via console.
I'm getting :

```
console.log(document.getElementById("#time1").value())
VM250:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')
    at <anonymous>:1:47
```

Can you give me some suggestions how to set the value of the time input,
if I'm getting a string value from an object.

For example: "06:00 AM"

I know that it will not accept that string since there's a unexpected character in it.

Comment: If you use `querySelector` you need to use `#` into selector if you use `getElementById` you must use only id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 errors in your code.

1 - No need to use # when you use `getElementById`. Because we are already telling browser to get by Id. However you would need # if you are using `querySelector`.

2. `value` is not a function.

So the code should be

`console.log(document.getElementById("time1").value)`

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp

Comment: Thanks.  Can you help me on how to set the value if I'm using a string value like `"6:00 AM"`

Comment: The value should be in 24 hour format while setting, regardless how it is displayed and without the AM or PM.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time#setting_the_value_using_javascript

Answer (score 1):

Dont use the # on the document.getElementById.

Use either

```
document.getElementById("time1");
//-- or --
document.querySelector("#time1");
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using value(), use value

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("time1").value);
```

```html
<input type="time" name="car" id="time1" value="18:00">
```